# Creating Individual Color In Console Window

Tags: c#, console

I am trying to make a maze game where the player is displayed with an icon '$'.

The player can use the arrow keys to move around the console window. The player will encounter enemies such as 'U'. This enemy moves only up and down. If the player contacts any enemies they will die.

This is the basic jist of my game. I have completed the games collisions and enemies and it all works perfectly sound. However I would like to add color to the objects in the game.

For example I would like it if my player character could be blue and the 'U' enemy can be red. I haven't been able to implement color without causing extreme slowness or flickering.

The way I have made my game is all the enemies are written to a `char[][]` array which holds all their positions. Then after all the movement and collisions are done for a specific tick the `char[][]` array is transferred to a string. I then print the string in one go to avoid any flickering.

However in order to change the color of my characters they need to be printed in seperate strings. This however will not allow me to change individual colors because `Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;` will change the color of the whole game because the whole game is printed to one string. I cannot figure out a way around this does anyone know a solution.

Also is there any way to draw things to the Console Window that doesn't use `Console.Write();` or `Console.WriteLine();` because I would like to output something to the console that isn't a string.

Comment: It is worth spending some time on learning [how to format posts with mini Markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting).

Comment: Back to the question, my instant feeling is that it would be _much easier_ to draw colored letters on a `WinForms`/`WPF` window; By using `WinForms`/`WPF` window, you can still have the look and feel of a `Console`. Of course, if you want to do it with `Console` just out of interest...Enjoy.